# Database connection from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm developping an application on Google App Engine and Google CloudSQL, but I met a curious behaviour today.

I have two CloudSQL instances, one is for developpment use and another is for commercial use.

I set my `persistence.xml` and "App Engine Settings -> Google Cloud SQL" developpment instance, and set "App Engine Settings -> Deployment -> version"  developpment version name, and deployed my application.

Then I changed those settings to the commercial instance and set version commercial version name, and deployed my application.

But curiously the commercial version is connected to developpment database instance.

Can anyone guess the reason?

Comment: you mean you deploying both development version and commercial under same projectId, just different versions?

Comment: that could be possible that Appengine is using a db pool shared between different versions

Comment: I don't see any confirmation in official docs (only some hints maybe), but it's very logical thing to do. And at this case you cannot avoid that. One suggestion - deploy different apps under different projectids, then you'll avoid such situations